# How to calculate values after scaling numbers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, matlab, octave

I have two number list old scale and the new scale.
What formula would I use to find the `new scale value` if the old scale value is 5.89345?  Is it possible to calculate the `new scale value` if the old scale value is 1.342? Or if the new scale value is 4.32 how would I figure out the `old scale value`

```
old scale           new scale
4                     2
5                   2.6                         
6                   3.2
7                   3.8
8                   4.4
9                     5
```

I'm coding this in Octave 4.0 which is similar to Matlab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume a linear model, then by inspection of your table,

$$y = 2 + 0.6(x-4)$$

(Do you see how I did that?)

Your old value is $x$ and the corresponding new value is $y$.

**Additional info based on your comments:**

If your data is in fact linear (you can draw a straight line exactly through all of the points) then all you need is two of the rows to fill out a table.

Your step size will be $m = (y_2-y_1)/(x_2-x_1)$.  The math term for this is the slope of the line.  Plugging in the numbers from your table above gives

$$m = \frac{2.6-2.0}{5-4} = 0.6.$$

As far as the programming part in Octave, I'm not familiar with that, but assuming you can program in Octave, that's how you get the step size.

Comment: wait how did you do that?

Comment: @John thanks will this same formula also work if the new scale value is 4.32 how would I figure out the `old scale value`.  I'm coding this in Octave 4.0 which is similar to matlab

Comment: What does the "new scale value" mean?  I thought it was just an additional point in the right column of your table.

Comment: But my intent was that if you have a value you want to add to the left column, call this $x$ and solve for the corresponding value in the right column, which is $y$.  If you want to go the other way, solve for $x$ in terms of $y$.

Comment: @John thanks I'm writing this in matlab I can figure out how to program / automate everything but the `0.6 stepsize` Is there a way to get / automate the 0.6 from the values in the new scale column if a new range of numbers is used?